# how to include js file using asset on yii2 advanced template

Tags: ajax, yii2-advanced-app

I have folowoed the following guide http://www.yiiplayground.com/yii2/web/index.php?r=ajax/index How can i include the js file using assets. the following file i have created under `/frontend/assets`

```
<?php 
namespace frontend\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

class AjaxAsset extends AssetBundle{
    public $basePath = '@frontend';
    public $baseUrl = '/view';
    public $css = [

    ];
    public $js = [
        'ajax/ajax.js',
    ];
    public $depends = [
    'yii\web\YiiAsset',
    'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ];

}
?>
```

I have managed to make it work by updating to the following

```
//public $basePath = '@webroot';
//public $baseUrl = '@web';
public $sourcePath = '@frontend/views/ajax';
```

However I am now having a problem with the javascript file.

**views/ajax/ajax.js**

```
'reportsviewDone': function (response) {
    // This is called by the link attribute 'data-on-done' => 'simpleDone'
    console.dir(response);
    $('#css3buttons').html(response.body);
}
```

I get syntax error

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
'reportsviewDone': function (response) {
```

I have fixed it by changing it to

```
var ajaxCallbacks = {
    'reportsviewDone': function (response) {
        // This is called by the link attribute 'data-on-done' => 'simpleDone'
        console.dir(response);
        $('#css3buttons').html(response.body);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need separate asset for this? If not, make use of the work that advanced template had done for you (they wouldn't call it template for nothing), use its site-wide AppAsset.php. Put

```
   public $js = [
       'js/ajax.js',
   ];
```

there and put ajax.js into frontend/web/js

I'm quite positive that `views` isn't the best place for js files.

Before making changes to `$basePath` and `$baseUrl`, make sure you're using them [properly](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html), as well as [aliases](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/667/yii-2-list-of-path-aliases-available-with-default-basic-and-advanced-app/).

Comment: why have they done it like that in the example? http://www.yiiplayground.com/yii2/web/index.php?r=ajax/index

Comment: We can only guess. The example proposes that there are many views, and there is dedicated script for each view. But if js scripts are huge enough to get benefit from separating them, it is better to use js build system and js modules instead of just conditionally loading scripts as Yii assets. Yii assets are primarily intended as reusable bundles of css+js that can be identified by their versions (e.g. how Yii deals with widget assets, Bootstrap and jQuery).

Though it is a good example of how js can be added to the page dynamically without any html mess.